# MongoDB - Find records in one collection that match string in 2nd collection

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, mapreduce

I have a MongoDB collection of product IDs/unique products attributes and a second collection of codes that relate to attributes common for products whose IDs are prefixed with those codes.

For example, two product IDs might be `aaa17859` and `aaa98542` so their code prefix is `aaa`.

I have several thousand codes, and the codes rarely change, so the 'codes' collection is more of a data repo. The products change frequently throughout the day, and imports can run from several hundred to a few thousand.

Currently, I am running the below to join the two sets together when the data is first loaded in.

```
import re

code_collection= list(db.codes.find())
for x in code_collection:   
    p = re.compile(x['CODE-PREFIX'] + '.*')
    db.productdataset.update({'productID': {'$regex': p}}, { '$set': {'codeData': x['data_property']}}, multi=True )
```

Pro to this method is that it reduces the number of calls I would otherwise have to make once the data is initially loaded.

Major con is that when the code collection is updated (say, a new common attribute), something similar has to be rerun against the entire product collection. Plus, depending on this list, it can take a little longer than I'd like to load in the data. Also, this means I can end up with a good deal of duplication. In general, this approach just seems a little kludgy.

What I would like to optimize is a method to join these two sets together in one call, thus preventing the rerun. I have been looking at a lot of `mapreduce` examples, but have had trouble figuring out how I would be able to use the prefix from the `code` collection to use regex and  look up it's related `productID`.

Answer (score 1):

You're turning the result of `db.codes.find()` into a list, but you're just iterating over it anyway. Why not just leave it in whatever form it arrives? If it can be converted to a list it can probably be iterated over. This would save you the time of conversion and mean you might not need to have a full list stored in memory.

Also `x` isn't a great name for the temporary value when you could just use `code` and take up only 3 more letters.